# Releasing two turtles per tick netlogo

Tags: time, netlogo, release, agent

I'm currently working on a model where I could simulated pedestrian movement while shopping. So, I have already figure some of things I need but I have been trying to figure out **how to release 2 turtles per tick** (like a pair) in a certain patch. Both turtles are release at the same time. My code is base from ant lines but it just releases all the num-of-pedestrians in one time and then the turtles start walking. the ticks also start after all turtles are release. I want the turtles to start "walking" as they enter.
Here is my code:

```
breed [ leadvisitors leadvisitor ]
breed [ visitors visitor ]

to setup
  clear-all
   setup-visitors
reset-ticks
end

to setup-visitors 
  create-leadvisitors num-of-pedestrians * 0.1    ;;create 10% of the total number of pedestrians
  [ 
    set demand-type "none"
    set color black
    set size 1
    setxy 0 16
    set heading 180
    set pen-size 1
    set destination one-of patches
    set wait-time -1
    set demand-lvl 0    
  ]
  create-visitors (num-of-pedestrians - (num-of-pedestrians * 0.1)) 
  [ set demand-type 0
    set size 1
    setxy 0 16
    set heading 180
    set pen-size 1
    set destination one-of patches
    set wait-time -1
    set demand-lvl 1
    set attracted? false
  ]  ]
end

to go
  if turtles = 0  [ stop ]

  ask turtles 
  [ 
    set-demand-type  
    have-demand
  ]  


  if ticks > 100 [ stop ]
  tick
  display-labels
end

;;;;; visitor's internal state of demand ;;;;;

to set-demand-type
  if demand-type = 0
  [ set demand-type "food"
    set color red
    let target (patches in-cone visitor-vision-depth visitor-view-angle) with [pcolor = red] 
  ]
end 

to have-demand  
  if demand-lvl = 0 
  [
    ifelse wait-time = -1 
    [ stroll ]

    [ set wait-time wait-time - 1
      if wait-time = 0
      [ stroll ]]
    ]

  if demand-lvl = 1
    [ ifelse wait-time = -1 
      [ stroll
        evaluate ]

      [ set wait-time wait-time - 1
        if wait-time = 0
        [ stroll 
          evaluate ]] 
    ] 
end 

to stroll 
if any? neighbors with [ pcolor = gray - 3 ]
  [ die ]

  ifelse any? neighbors with [ pcolor = gray or pcolor = orange or pcolor = blue or pcolor = red]
  [ facexy exitpt-x exitpt-y ]
  [ rt random-float visitor-view-angle lt random-float visitor-view-angle ]
  fd walking-speed  
end

to evaluate 
  if any? neighbors with [ pcolor = gray or pcolor = orange or pcolor = blue or pcolor = gray - 4 or pcolor = gray - 3 or pcolor = red + 2]
  [ facexy exitpt-x exitpt-y 
    rt random-float visitor-view-angle lt random-float visitor-view-angle 
    fd walking-speed ]

  let _mycolor color
  if any? (patches in-cone visitor-vision-depth visitor-view-angle) with [pcolor = _mycolor]
  [ let new-target max-one-of ( patches with [pcolor = _mycolor] in-cone visitor-vision-depth visitor-view-angle) [patch-influence]
    let dist-to-new-target min-one-of (patches with [pcolor = _mycolor] in-cone visitor-vision-depth visitor-view-angle) [distance myself]
    face new-target
    set heading towards new-target
    fd walking-speed   
    set attracted? true       

    attracted-and-visiting
    re-evaluate 
   ]


end 

to attracted-and-visiting        
   if pcolor = red + 2
   [ set heading towards one-of patches with [pcolor = red + 2]
     fd 0
     set patch-popularity patch-popularity + 1
     set wait-time avg-waiting-time 

    if count turtles-here > 0
        [ set num-of-visitors num-of-visitors + 1 ]
          set plabel num-of-visitors 
   ]      
end


to re-evaluate
  let _mycolor color
  if not any? (patches in-cone visitor-vision-depth visitor-view-angle) with [pcolor = _mycolor]
  [ set attracted? false ]

  ifelse choose? [set heading towards one-of patches with [pcolor = _mycolor]] [facexy exitpt-x exitpt-y]    
end


to-report choose?
  report random 2 = 0
end
```

Comment: We will need to see your `go` procedure to be more specific, but essentially in that procedure you will have the desired patch `sprout 2 visitors []` where you would put in the brackets size, color, heading, etc,  Once they are created, they will obey all the same rules as any other visitor in terms of walking.  They will simply join the agentset of `visitors`.

Comment: Hi @Charles, I tried sprout 2 visitor [ ]. visitors was highlighted and the "expected command" prompt at the top.

Comment: my code is actually quite lengthy.. I added they full code above.. hope it helps.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry - my syntax was wrong.  It should be `sprout-visitors 2 []`. (The brackets are not necessary if there is nothing to put inside them.)  I'll check the rest of your code, but the incorrect syntax was likely the problem.  Alas, we all make mistakes!

Answer (score 3):

As a result of our back-and-forth comments, let me take a stab at what you are looking for. I assume that you want to create `leadvisitors` at the beginning of the run and then add two `visitors` per tick as the run progresses.  If so, then your `setup` procedure would look something like

```
globals [num-visitors-created]

to setup
  clear-all
  set num-visitors-created 0
  create-leadvisitors num-of-pedestrians * 0.1  [
    set demand-type "none"
    set color black
    set size 1
    setxy 0 16
    set heading 180
    set pen-size 1
    set destination one-of patches
    set wait-time -1
    set demand-lvl 0
    set num-visitors-created num-visitors-created + 1
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

creating your `leadvisitors`, but no `visitors`. Note that the global variable `num-visitors-created` keeps track of the number of `leadvisitors` and `visitors` created, being incremented by one each time a `leadvisitor` or `visitor` is created.

In your `go` procedure, you would then create two visitors each tick until the total number of `visitors` and `leadvisitors` created reaches `num-of-pedestrians`. (If there is room for only one new visitor, would you want just one to be created, or do they need to be created in pairs?  I'm assuming the latter.)  Since you don't want the death of a visitor to open up space for a new one, we test the number created, not the number still alive.

```
to go
  if turtles = 0  [ stop ]

  ; create a new pair of visitors if there is room.
  if num-visitors-created <= (num-of-pedestrians - 2)
    create-visitors 2 [ 
      set demand-type 0
      set size 1
      set heading 180
      set pen-size 1
      setxy 0 16
      set destination one-of patches
      set wait-time -1
      set demand-lvl 1
      set attracted? false
      set num-visitors-created num-visitors-created + 1
    ]

  ask turtles 
  [ 
    set-demand-type  
    have-demand
  ]

  if ticks > 100 [ stop ]
  tick
  display-labels
end
```

(Since it appears that `leadvisitors` may die as well, do you want to keep a certain minimum number or proportion of `leadvisitors`?  If so, you should open up a new question.)

The code above will create the pair of new `visitors` on `patch 0 16` at each tick. If, however, you want to have the new `visitors` created on a different patch, say one of the red ones, you could in your `go` procedure have that patch `sprout` the new visitors.

```
  ask one-of patches with [pcolor = red] [
    sprout-visitors 2 [ 
      set demand-type 0
      set size 1
      set heading 180
      set pen-size 1
      set destination one-of patches
      set wait-time -1
      set demand-lvl 1
      set attracted? false
      set num-visitors-created num-visitors-created + 1
    ]
  ]
```

Note that here the xy coordinates of the new visitors are not set, so they start on the patch that sprouted them.

Comment: Hello Charles, the first one works for me. But did add 'create-visitors 2 / num-of-pedestrians. so that the visitor count won't exceed the total number of pedestrians which is controlled by a slider. One more thing, as stated on my question. I wanted two visitors to walk as soon as they are release. but with this one, the tick count only starts when all of the visitors have been released. Is there a way for visitors to start "walking" and the tick count starts as the first two visitors are released?

Comment: Lyne, I'm not sure that `create-visitors 2 / num-of-pedestrians` does what you want.  I assume that `num-of-pedestrians` is large, so your division will yield a small fraction that NetLogo will round down to zero. No visitors will be created. I've edited my answer to include that constraint. The new line finds the lesser of two numbers, `2` and the value of your slider less the current number of visitors. (I'm assuming `num-of-pedestrians` is that slider value.)

Comment: I'm also assuming that pedestrians includes only `visitors`, not also `leadvisitors`. If both are to be included, they you want `count turtles` as both visitors and `leadvisitors` are turtles.

Comment: I'm a bit uncertain about your setup, then.  Your `setup` creates `num-of-pedestrians` (`leadvisitors` and `visitors`) all at once, before the first tick, They won't start moving until the `go` procedure is started, at wich point all will move.  Do you want to start with fewer pedestrians and then gradually add more over "time" until you get to the maximum number?

Comment: Hi Charles, the new code doesn't quite work for me because now after the total number of pedestrians are release eg. 10, another batch of 10 visitors also come out and so on.

Comment: What I want is that at first 2 visitors are released (time starts ticking as soon as the first two are release) until all visitors have been release based on the total num-of-pedestrian slider. Eg. if there are 10 visitors, they will be released by twos until all 10 have been released. Both leadvisitors and visitors are include in the total num-of-pedestrians.

Comment: Lyne, see if my edited answer give you what you want.

Comment: Hi Charles, thank you so much for your answer. Most of the code is working for me. Tick count starts as a pair of visitors are released. But the only thing that doesn't work for me is that whenever the some visitors die, a new pair is release which is not what I would have wanted. I wanted to release visitors based from the total number of pedestrians. Eg. num-of-pedestrians = 10, if the visitor count has reached 10, then no visitors wont be released anymore because it has reach the maximum num-of-pedestrians. I tried editing the code to fix it, but I still can't figure it out.

Comment: I know this has been a long conversation but if you can still help me solve this. I would appreciate it.

Comment: Certainly Lyne.  I've edited the code to add a counter that keeps track of the number of visitors created and, when that reaches `num-of-pedestrians`, no more will be created. I assume you have other `globals` in your model, so you can add `num-visitors-created` to that list of globals.  If not, the `globals` statement goes at the beginning of the code, where you have defined the breeds, etc.

Comment: I can't run your code without having the full model, so there might be some typos, but hopefully this will get you going.  If you think this will do it, you should "Accept" this answer so that this thread can be tied off.  Cordially,

Comment: Your latest code still doesn't work for me. the closes one is with 'if count turtles <= (num-of-pedestrians - 2) [ create-visitors 2 [ ..] ] But, thank you for all the comments and suggestions.

Comment: the visitors are continuously released so it exceeds the total num-of-pedestrians. What I want is.. eg. the num-of-pedestrians is 10, I want to release two turtles at a time (so tick count starts as the first two "walks") until all 10 are released. so total visitor count will not exceed 10.

Comment: I don't see why that should be so.  Can you send me your full .nlogo model file?

Comment: Oh I just rechecked. It does worked! I did not add the last line in my code. It's okay now. Thank you.

Comment: Great!  Good luck with your project.